# Is there any footage of the Argo meeting the Golden Hind?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, jason-and-the-argonauts-1963

I have read online that during the filming of the famous 1963 fantasy film *[Jason and the Argonauts](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057197/)* and the British television series *[Sir Francis Drake](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055656/)*, both of which involved sailing period ships around the Mediterranean, the two crews accidentally accidentally came in sight of one-another while both were filming.

Naturally this ruined the footage, and there was supposedly some annoyance on the parts of both crews, until producer [Charles H. Schneer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Schneer) (who may have been on the Argo on one of the nearby craft with cameras) got onto his bullhorn and yelled to the crew of the Golden Hind that they were in the wrong century — humorously defusing the situation.

It seems unlikely that, even if this is really how the event played out, that there would be any surviving footage of the event, with the Argo and the Golden Hind together in the shot.  However, if there is, that seems like it would be really cool.  So has any effort been made to determine whether such film exists?

Comment: You may want to edit in the actual source of this story (*[Ray Harryhausen: An Animated Life](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/632268))* - It's excerpted in the Guardian here - https://www.theguardian.com/books/2003/dec/20/featuresreviews.guardianreview16

Comment: *"Everything was ready, the camera was rolling and we radioed the ship to start off. But what should come around the bluff but the Golden Hinde. The tension was broken when Schneer was heard to shout, "Get that ship out of here! You're in the wrong century."*

Comment: Based on the description they appear to have stopped filming, film in those days being an expensive and limited resource, when the wrong ship rounded the cove. Presumably a few seconds of that footage exists (or at least, existed at some point). Probably it ended up in a bonfire somewhere.

Comment: Other versions of the story exist. https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Greek_and_Roman_Mythology/OZrCmfl8VygC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the+wrong+century%22&dq=%22the+wrong+century%22&printsec=frontcover

Comment: In this version (1971 - Punch) it's not the Golden Hind, but rather "*a Spanish Galleon*" - https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Punch/MmQPAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22jeep%22&dq=%22jeep%22&printsec=frontcover